# Problema al sacar la longitud de una variable extraida de JS a PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Cuando extraigo la variable `variablejs`, el valor aparece normalmente, pero cuando quiero sacar la longitud de esta, no coincide

```
<script>
  var variablejs = "1002";
</script>

<?php
  $phpvariable ="<script>document.write(variablejs)</script>";

  // He probado extraerlo pero nada, el valor es el conjunto de 43 caracteres...
  $extraccion = substr($phpvariable, 0, 43);

  echo var_dump($phpvariable);
?>
```

Comment: Quieres obtener la longitud de `variablejs` usando substr ??

Comment: Lo que sucede es que estas viendo la variable `$variablejs` ejecutada mediante el script que tiene, pero al hacerle un `strlen()` te mostrará un 43 porque **esa es la cantidad de caracteres que contiene contando las etiquetas y todo lo demás**

Comment: Ahhh ya comprendi que quiere hacer, no quiere obtener el valor de `$phpvariable`, sino el de `variablejs`...

Comment: Exacto quiere obtener el valor pero en el PHP

Comment: En realidad el problema no es que la longitud este mal porque en realidad es correcta, el error es la forma en la que se obtiene el valor.

Comment: Claro Israel-ICM, el valor si que es el correcto. Pero como lo quiero usar como claúsula en un where de mysql no puedo mandarle por ejemplo un Id=1 pero que tiene un string de 43 caracteres.

Comment: Exacto no podrás enviar el valor de 43 caracteres, esa es la razón por la que comentaba que la forma de recuperar el valor de JavaScript posiblemente no era la correcta

Answer (score 1):

La forma en que obtienes el valor puede resultar «engañosa», ya que no es *PHP* quien imprime realmente el valor de la variable sino de nuevo *JavaScript*, aunque es cierto que en ocasiones muy concretas puede resultarnos de gran utilidad.

Por lo tanto *PHP* no almacena el valor, sino que es realmente *JavaScript* quien lo interpreta en nuestro navegador web, ya que PHP se ejecutó en tiempo mucho antes en el lado del servidor web.

La solución entonces pasa porque el evento *JavaScript* lance una petición web a *PHP* que provoque un click a una página PHP, y que acabe pasando los parámetros por POST o GET asignándolos así a las variables correspondientes.

Haré referencia a [esta pagina](https://academy.leewayweb.com/como-pasar-una-variable-de-javascript-a-php/) para que comprendas lo que pasa.

> **Por qué no se puede pasar directamente un valor de Js a PHP**
>
> El punto es que PHP y JavaScript se ejecutan en lugares y momentos diferentes.
>
> Es como si estuvieses leyendo un libro y te encontraras con algo que
> no comprendes del todo y para solucionarlo le hicieras la pregunta al
> libro… algo no va a funcionar.
>
> Empecemos entonces por comprender el ciclo de vida de una aplicación
> web.
>
> **Cómo es el ciclo de vida de una aplicación web**
>
> El flujo típico de una aplicación web es el siguiente:
>
> 1. El cliente hace un pedido al servidor (Envía un comando HTTP)
> 2. El servidor lo recibe y lo analiza
> 3. Si se trata de un php se lo pasa al intérprete correspondiente
> 4. El intérprete procesa el código y genera una salida (Usualmente HTML)
> 5. El servidor envía la salida hacia el cliente
> 6. El cliente analiza la respuesta y dibuja la página
> 7. El cliente ejecuta el código Js
>
> Entonces, si observás este ciclo, te darás cuenta que, para el momento
> en que la variable Js aparece en escena… php ya está haciendo
> cualquier otra cosa.
>
> Un ejemplo de lo que podrías hacer es usando AJAX:
>
> ```
> <?php $var = 1;
> ?>
> <html>
>     <body>
>         <input type="button" value="Enviar variable" id="send"/>
>     </body>
>     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>         $('#send').click(function() {
>             alert('Enviando!');
>             $.ajax({
>                 url: 'get_var.php?var=<?php echo $var; ?>',
>                 success: function( data ) {
>                     alert( 'El servidor devolvio "' + data + '"' );
>                 }
>             })
>         });
>     </script>
> </html>
> ```
>
> Y el get_var.php
>
> ```
> <?php
> echo 'Recibi '.$_GET['var'];
> ```

Otra forma que tienes es usando el típico formulario y enviar el dato por POST o GET.

Comment: Hola, Lo que ocurre es que hay mas trasfondo de lo que he puesto, solo lo he resumido, en el ejemplo que me has puesto se supone que aquí echo 'Recibi '.$_GET['var']; tiene que imprimir 1 no? A mi me sale un alert con la cabeceta html del sitio, no se si ese es el resultado esperado.

Comment: Bueno el código que puse es un ejemplo que debería ser modificado según a lo que necesitas, en este caso en el archivo `get_var.php` debería estar el `var_dump` que muestras en tu ejemplo en lugar de `echo 'Recibi '.$_GET['var'];`. Debería mostrar un `alert` con ese `echo` que realizaste.

Comment: Vale gracias, ya he conseguido lo que quería hacer, al final tuve que auto ejecutar un commit con un evento en js y pasar la variable por post con ajax. Solucionado.